# Improper facet_wrap output

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

The below is my sample data

[image: Sample Data]

Though there are values for mobile and tablet across all 4 dates, when I try to facet_wrap across device category, my results are not what is expected. All the values corresponding to each date are being added to the desktop only and are not being distributed across the 3 categories.

The code that I used is

```
qplot(data=gaData, x=gaData$Date, y=gaData$Users, xlim = c(20170101,20170101))+
  facet_wrap(~gaData$Device.Category, ncol = 1)
```

The output that I'm seeing in the plot is

[image: Sample Output]

I'm new to the whole data visualization area. I'm unable to identify what is wrong with the code.

P.S. I'm able to plot mobile and tablet individually for the same dates successfully as individual plots.

Comment: pictures are not code/or data unless the topic is image processing. `dput()` use is suggested in the [r tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info). The goal is to help others help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- data.frame(Date = c('2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-02','2017-01-02','2017-01-02','2017-01-03','2017-01-03','2017-01-03',
                         '2017-01-04','2017-01-04','2017-01-04'), Device = c("desktop","mobile","tablet","desktop","mobile","tablet",
                                                                             "desktop","mobile","tablet","desktop","mobile","tablet"),
                Users = c(404,223,39,529,211,43,1195,285,29,1019,275,35))
x$Date <- as.POSIXct(x$Date, tz = "UTC")

ggplot(x, aes(Date, Users)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~Device)
```

[image]

Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
# Simulate some dummy data
dat <- data.frame(
    Date = rep(20170101:20170104, each = 3),
    Device = rep(c('D', 'M', 'T'), 4),
    Users = runif(n = 12, max = 1000, min = 10) %>% round()
)

# This is the 'base map', map variables onto aesthetics
ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Users, col = Device), data = dat) + 
    # What kind of geometry?
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    # From 1d panel to 2d
    facet_wrap(~Device, ncol = 1)
```

[Plot Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o6hN.png)

You may also consider converting `Date` variable to class `date`.

The following references hope to help you gain some understanding of ggplot2.

1. http://tutorials.iq.harvard.edu/R/Rgraphics/Rgraphics.html
2. http://r-statistics.co/Complete-Ggplot2-Tutorial-Part1-With-R-Code.html
3. http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/

Also, [DataCamp](https://www.datacamp.com/) provides wonderful online tutorials.

Welcome to the amazing world of R. Cheers.

Comment: Nice answer, but please include packages that you used.

Comment: What is the difference from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest you convert 'Date' to POSIXct. I use lubridate package:

```
library(lubridate)
Date=ymd(c(rep("2017-01-01",3),rep("2017-01-02",3),rep("2017-01-03",3),rep("2017-01-04",3)))
```

then we can build the rest of the dat frame

```
Country=rep("United States",12)
Device.Category=rep(c("Desktop","Mobile","Tablet"),4)
Users=c(404,223,39,529,211,43,1195,285,29,1019,275,35)
df=data.frame(Date,Country,Device.Category,Users)
```

If you want to plot only for "2017-01-01" use this

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=Date,y=Users))+geom_point()+facet_grid(Device.Category~.)+xlim(ymd("2017-01-01"),ymd("2017-01-01"))
```

[image]

Or if you want all dates just remove the xlim function

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=Date,y=Users))+geom_point()+facet_grid(Device.Category~.)+xlim(ymd("2017-01-01"),ymd("2017-01-01"))
```

[image]